# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)

Tags: php

I Trying to store 3 data values to mysql database using PHP PDO they are just 3 strings name,username,password. and got this fatal error.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in D:\xampp\htdocs\fiverr\order-management-system\classes\contr\UserContr.class.php on line 13
>
> My Current php.ini data limit =
> ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
> ; http://php.net/memory-limit
> memory_limit=512M

```
    // User Modal-------------------------------
    <?php

    require_once "Dbcon.php";

    class User extends Dbcon{

    //check table is empty 

    protected function if_tableEmpty(){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_login";

    $stmt = $this->connect()->query($sql);

    $result = $stmt->rowCount();
    
    if($result > 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

//check username is already exist

protected function username_exists($username){

    if($this->if_tableEmpty() != true){

        $this->username = $username;

    
        $sql = "SELECT username FROM user_login WHERE username = ?";

        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute([$this->username]);

        $result = $stmt->rowCount();

        return $result;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
    
    
        
}

// User Insert
protected function setUser($name, $username, $password, $type, $status){

    $this->name = $name;

    $this->username = $username;

    $this->password = $password;

    $this->type = $type;

    $this->status = $status;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_login(name, username, password, type, status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";

    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);

    $insert = $stmt->execute([$this->name, $this->username, $this->password, $this->type, $this->status]);

    if($insert == true){

        return true;

    }else{

        return false;
    }

}
}
    // User Controller-------------------------------
    require_once "./classes/modal/User.class.php";

    class UserContr extends User{

    // check username exists

    public function username_exists($username){

    $this->username = $username;

    $result = $this->username_exists($this->username);

    if($result > 0){

        return true;

    }else{

        return false;

    }

}

// create marketer

public function create_marketer($name, $username, $password){

    if($this->username_exists($username) == false){

        $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $type = 'marketer';

        $status = 'active';
        
        $result = $this->setUser($name, $username, $password, $type, $status);

        if($result == true){

            return true;

        }else{

            return false;

        }
    }else{

        return 1;

    }

}
}
    //Posting php file in includes folder

   <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];

        if(!empty($name) && !empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($confirm_password)){

            

            if($confirm_password != $password){

                $alert = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <strong><i class="fas fa-info"></i> Password Not Match!</strong> Confirm Password not matched try again.
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                </div>';

                echo $alert;

            }else{

                $result = $marketer->create_marketer($name, $username, $password);

                if($result == true){

                    $alert = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <strong><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Success!</strong> Marketer created successfully.
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    </div>';

                    echo $alert;

                }elseif($result == false){

                    $alert = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <strong><i class="fas fa-info"></i> Failed!</strong> Marketer creating failed try again. If this error persists, please contact the developer.
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    </div>';

                    echo $alert;

                }elseif($result == 1){

                    $alert = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <strong><i class="fas fa-info"></i> Try Again!</strong> Marketer username already exist please try another username.
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    </div>';

                    echo $alert;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

?>

this is first time got this error. I worked before lots of project with PHP PDO and i never got this error before. i tried to fix changing php.ini different memory_limits but not fixed. its has wasted 2 days for this. please help me to fix this. thank you!

Comment: Can you show `username_exists` method code?

Comment: yes i can. i edited the question please check. thank you!

Comment: The amount of memory is not the problem; the problem is something is consuming it. Recursion or binary data  might be involved. Double check the query works outside of php, try inserting one thing at a time and then add variables until it breaks. I would bet the problem is either the query or the data.

Comment: 262144 is suspiciously round number

Comment: and what is the line 13 exactly?

Comment: First of all, give us compleate class to we can look at lines. Second, check do you edit good php.ini file. Do you have some loop where you save data to string or array? What is your script execution time?

Comment: 1.['Tim Morton' Thank you I will try.! ] 2[ Your Common Sense here is line 13 $stmt = $this->connect()->query($sql); thank you!] 3[Ivijan Stefan Stipic i edited the question please check thank you]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks For Everyone who tried to help me to solve this. Anyway I found the problem. It's my mistake: I have used the same method name inside of UserView.class.php and User.class.php. The method name is username_exists. Here is the problematic code.

```
//this is the method in modal class

protected function username_exists($username){

    if($this->if_tableEmpty() != true){

        $this->username = $username;

    
        $sql = "SELECT username FROM user_login WHERE username = ?";

        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute([$this->username]);

        $result = $stmt->rowCount();

        return $result;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
    
    
        
}

   //This is the method in Controller class

   public function username_exists($username){

    $this->username = $username;

    $result = $this->username_exists($this->username);

    if($result > 0){

        return true;

    }else{

        return false;

    }

}
```

Thanks again to all of you!

Comment: so it was a recursion